# Calendar object time mismatch with Android phone time

Tags: android

I've built one small reminder app demo, where user fill some details and get notified. When I set the notification time, after current time to 5 minutes later like if current time is 14:55, then I'm setting 15:00 with current date. Now, notification is coming perfectly on time, when I do nothing and simply wait for 5 minutes to over.

But, when I manually go to my Android phone, and set time to 4 minutes later (14:59) and after wait for 1 minutes, notification is not coming. Why?

**Code:**
**Manifest:**

```
<application
...

 <receiver android:name=".Receiver.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".Receiver.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

**AlarmReceiver**

```
    public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        /*mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        isAlarmSet = (mPendingIntent != null);
        if (isAlarmSet) {
            showLog("isAlarmSet: " + isAlarmSet);
        } else {
            showLog("isAlarmSet: " + isAlarmSet);
        }*/

        // Calculate notification time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // Start alarm using notification time
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }


    public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Cancel Alarm using Reminder ID
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);

        // Disable alarm
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
}
```

**AddReminderActivity:**

```
private void setReminderAlarm(int id) {
        String mDate = tvDueDate.getText().toString();
        if (mDate.equals("")) {
            mDate = CommonUtils.getDate();
        }
        String mTime = tvAlarmTime.getText().toString();

        String[] mDateSplit = mDate.split("-");
        String[] mTimeSplit = mTime.split(":");

        mDay = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[2]);
        mMonth = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[1]) - 1;
        mYear = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[0]);
        mHour = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[0]);
        mMinute = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[1]);


        // Check repeat type
        long mRepeatTime = 0;

        // Create a new notification
        int day = mDay - notificationDay;

            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay - notificationDay);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), mCalendar, id);
        }
```

Comment: You should modify the alarm on broadcast receiver time changed event

Comment: @ManojPerumarath what does it mean?

Comment: Do you know how a broadcast receiver works?

Comment: Yes, but explain please

Comment: Using a broadcast that will listen for time_change you will get to know that the time has been altered. So in that case you can cancel the alarm or do a precise calculation for adjusting the case, the other solution is which i have mentioned as answe, you can set a millis to alarm, which is not related with system clock there by the alarm won't get affected

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Can you give some example of your first solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should use AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP while setting your alarm. AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP will trigger the alarm according to the time of the clock.

Example code:

`mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                currentTime + diffTime,
                mPendingIntent);`

Comment: Notification coming immediately, even though I sat at after 5 minutes.

Comment: I have edited my answer. As you are using clock time in your code. You should should use Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() instead of SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(). Former method returns wall clock time in milliseconds and later returns time in milliseconds since device boot.

Answer (score 0):

By using `TIME_SET` receiver you can get to notify about the system time has been changed.

Whenever you're creating an Alarm just save the time in a local db also. When the broadcast receiver is triggered invoke a service, inside that fetch all existing alarm time with the new system time. You should be aware that **all the alarms will get cancelled once you change the system time**. So you should recreate all your alarms.

Comment: I tried this solution, but my motive is different. I've functionality that user can set Reminder for month/week/year. Now I want to test that after 1 year my notification will come or not? How can I do that? Obviously by manually changing android date & time.

Comment: It's not good to save a todo/reminder that should be notified after a long time. It should be kept in the server side, at the time of the event a push notification should be sent by the server to the phone

Comment: I know, but currently please give solution for SQLite

Comment: It is not cancelling, but coming after 3-4 minutes

Comment: there's something wrong then inside your code for setting alarm, it should get cancelled once there's a time change

Comment: Forget about mycode, I made one very small short demo, it is not canceled. See: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-scheduled-task-example/

Comment: Did you see that he's using AlarmManager.RTC while setting the alarm, that's the point

Comment: What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`mAlarmManager.set()` does not force to deliver the pending intent at the exact given time

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)
>
> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up" and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the future.

`mAlarmManager.setExact()` may fit what you are trying to do

if you have the exact time and date, (year, month, day, hour and minute) (you can check that with android studio debugger or with logcat to print the values) you can set the alarm with
`mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, /*your exact time in millis*/, mPendingIntent`);

Comment: edited with the correct alarm type (RTC_WAKEUP) so you can set the exact time in millis (basically the mCalendar you pass in setAlarm() so you dont have to get the difference between now and your alarm